Expo app crashing on device but working on simulator
I have an expo app using react-native-firebase and I noticed that the tab where information is fetched from my firestore database crashes the app. As soon as I tap to move to the tab the app crashes. Everything else works fine. The app works perfectly on the simulator but when I did an internal distribution build to my iPhone 15 Pro it crashes on that tab that fetches firestore data. Does anyone have any idea why? It works fine in the simulator so this doesn't make sense to me and makes it challenging since I cannot reproduce the error.
Thanks in advance!

I suggest you use some tool to debug your app on a real device. Maybe you get more information about the crash on a real device. Connect your iPhone to get the device UDID with the command xcrun simctl list devices. After this, you can run npx expo run:ios -d "UDID|DEVICE_NAME" and debug your app.

Hi Marcelo, I currently have an internal distribution built with EAS build. You do eas create to add a device and its UUID and then install the app on the device. Your command isn't working for me. Do I need to install the app on the device another way or connect the phone to my macbook with a usb cable?

Hi! That's it, you need to install your app on your iPhone connecting it to your MacBook by USB cable. The commands that were passed needed an iPhone connected to a MacBook

I am getting this error ⚠️  Something went wrong running pod install in the ios directory.
Command pod install failed.
└─ Cause: Invalid Podfile file: exit. When I run it with sudo it says pod can't run with root permissions. I am kind of helpless. I think it is an issue with firebase but I have no idea what.

The ios directory contains native files by your app. The pod install is a command from CocoaPods (it manages library dependencies for Xcode projects), this command installs all dependencies listed at Podfile. The expo runs it with expo start or expo build:ios. How did you install the react-native-firebase and firestone libraries? Maybe it's a problem with the configuration

I installed it with npm and added the plist file to the main folder. The configuration should be correct because it works perfectly on the simulator. It only crashes on the real device. I am using eas build to create the builds and install it on the device with a preview profile, so I am not familiar with this other way. I am also getting this permission error when I run npx expo run:ios At the same time I think something minor could be causing the crash but without logs it's so hard to find out.

Ok. I found this issue on the Expo repo, the same message error appears for you, Cause: Invalid Podfile file: exit. Could you try these commands?

do you have any update about the problem?

I know it's react-native-firebase causing the crash when I fetch data with firestore. I am using the web modular API as a workaround but that isn't safe. Before it goes to production I'll have to solve the problem, I just have no idea why it's crashing.

After many days struggling turns out it was a problem with react-native-firebase and expo. In this thread you can read more about the problem. I chose to upgrade to Expo 50 and the latest versions of react-native-firebase and its submodules and that fixed the problem for me. Thank you Marcelo Freires for your help!
